# How would I inject code from my Chrome extension into a webpage?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, code-injection

I have been recently trying to build a chrome extension and I have a piece of code that needs to declare a function on a webpage. I have been able to successfully inject code into the webpage via the console but how would I make my chrome extension run my code when something like a button is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a good Explanation here : [Google Developer Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

Short Guide:

- Create a content-script
- Add it to your manifest.
- get the Body: `const $body = $("body")`
- Insert your content: `$body.append("Content");`

Attention: In your manifest you need the tabs permission